# Implementing a lock free data structure on disk

Tags: c++, multithreading, data-structures, b-tree, lock-free

I have an interesting challenge, for those with strong background in lock-free data structures, and disk based data structures.

I'm looking for a way to build in C++ a data structure to hold a varying amount of objects.

The limitation are such:

1. The data structure must reside on disk.
2. There is one thread writing to the data structure and many others reading from it.
3. Every read is atomic. (lets assume I can atomically read a block of size 32/64KB for this  and that all objects are small than that in size.
4. A write should not block a read, for that it is possible to assume that I can write in an atomic way a block of 32/64KB as well.
5. Locks cannot be used at all.

Any suggestions?

I was thinking of using something like a B-Tree and when needed to split nodes and write new data than move them to new nodes at the end of the file and then just update the pointers to the nodes which will reside for example in some other file (the original blocks will be marked as free and added to a freestore)

However, I run into a problem if my mapping file is greater than 32/64Kb.. Let say I want it to hold even just 1 million object pointers than at 4 bytes/pointer I get to 4 million bytes which is roughly 4 Megs... (and at 1 billion objects even more than that..) Which means the mappings file cannot be written in an atomic manner.

So if someone has a better suggestion as to maybe how to implement the above - or even some direction it would be greatly appreciated.

As far as I know all opensource/commercial implementations of B-Tree use locks of some sort, which I cannot use.

Thanks,
Max.

Comment: But do you really need to write the whole map file? Won't it be enough to update only the block that have changed?

Comment: I don't see how you can do this without lock...

Comment: This is impossible in the way you describe, because OS file access API implicitly has a reader-writer kind of lock - i.e. you basically use OS's mutexes instead of your own.

Comment: As @DarkWanderer says, the OS is going to use locks to prevent concurrent access to the disk. You probably should use a memory mapped file and look into lock-free B-Tree implementations. http://www.cs.umanitoba.ca/~hacamero/Research/BtreeTechrpt2011.pdf is an interesting read. Also, out of curiousity, why are you prohibited from using locks?

Comment: I have trouble comprehending 'lock free' and 'disk' in the same sentence.

Comment: Lets assume for the sake of the argument that MY os, or specifically filesystem allows me to do concurrent reads/writes. Meaning that they are not using any locks but are atomic only on the level of a block sized 32/64KB (that's why I mentioned it)

Answer (score 4):

You won't get very far by just assuming reads/writes are atomic -- mainly because they're not, and you'll end up emulating it in a way that'll kill performance.

It sounds like you want to research [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control), which is the pretty standard mechanism to use when designing a lock-free database. The basic concept is that every read gets a "snapshot" of the database -- usually implemented in a lock-free way by leaving old pages alone and performing any modifications to new pages only. Once the old pages are finished being used by readers, they're finally marked for re-use.

While MVCC is significantly more involved than a CPU/RAM lock-free structure, once you have it many of the same optimistic lock-free patterns apply towards using it.

Comment: As mentioned above, assume that in my filesystem they are atomic, for the sake of the design. MVVC looks promising I will have to research more into it and see how I can adapt the concept to my disk storage, as opposed to memory storage.

Comment: Well actually MVCC does not solve my problem, as my data structure requires to be sortable - hence allow doing next/prev operations on the data. MVCC solves a problem for a hashable table, but it does not provide sorting..

Comment: MVCC doesn't have anything to do with your data structure other than providing lock-free operation. It is commonly used with B+trees in databases, but can really be used for anything.

Comment: I undersand that more or less, but using MVCC with what I'm trying to do requires a huge overhead as far as I understand. (if you have to repeat the object versioning process for every hop in the B+ tree that is inefficient)

Comment: Additionally I am trying to optimize for my read/write atomicity, if for my end 32/64KB writes are atomic, it means I can potentially try and cache large portions of the tree mapping to boost performance. (fore example if using b+ trees instead of b-tree I can cache references to quite a few members in one read to optimize performance)

Answer (score 1):

LMDB will do all of this with no problem. It is an MVCC B+tree and readers are completely lockless.